# What's wrong with this cross product of two vectors?

Tags: warning-messages, vector

```
x = {{a},{b},{c}};
y = {{d},{e},{f}};
Cross[x,y]
```

Whe trying to evaluate this expression, I get the error `Cross: The arguments are expected to be vectors of equal length, and the number of arguments is expected to be 1 less than their length.` I really have no idea what's wrong with this input, can anybody explain?

Comment: `x` and `y` are not a vectors, they are matrices: `VectorQ[x]` returns `False` while `MatrixQ[x]` returns `True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
x = {a, b, c};
y = {d, e, f};
Cross[x, y]
```

Comment: Seems really mysterious to me, but it works. Can you explain what's wrong with my original code?

Comment: Cross expects lists as argument. Your definition of x,y is something like a list of lists.

Comment: It's what I get when I enter what I expect to be a column vector. Input on keyboard is `x = ( Ctrl+Enter Ctrl+Enter` and then fill the fields and close parenthesis. From what I've read just now, vectors seem to always appear as row vectors in Mathematica. I strongly prefer the clearly arranged look of column vectors, is there any way to enter them as well?

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized that Mathematica doesn't include things as 'vector' and 'matrix', there are just nested lists of the shape `{x,y,z,...}`.

Answer (score 2):

If you really prefer column vectors, then you can define

```
cross[x_, y_] := Transpose @ List @ Cross[Join @@ x, Join @@ y];
```

and then the modified code

```
x = {{a}, {b}, {c}};
y = {{d}, {e}, {f}};
cross[x, y]
```

returns the result you expected:

```
{{-c e + b f}, {c d - a f}, {-b d + a e}}
```